# Next.js blank page after rewriting the server on Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, sass, next.js

I'm making a Next.js app with a express server, this server was written on Javascript, but after some learning on Typescript, I decided to move that server to Typescript

When I started the app on development mode and went to localhost to check if the site was working, the page was blank, I thought it some front-end error, so I opened the browser console, nothing, so I decided to inspect element the page, and to my surprise, the CSS on the page had these properties.

[image: Browser inspect element]

So the page didn't showed any content, I removed that property, and the html showed, but without styles, so I went back to my IDE and deleted node_modules, re-installed everything but nothing has worked so far.

I did not change the server's code nor the page's code in any way, I just added types and interfaces for some custom types on the server

So I started to make some "debugging" on the page, and after some experimenting, I realised that the problem was that it couldn't import the scss from the files

(the "debugging")

[image: code]

[image: result]

So the problem that the files can't be imported, I tried renaming them, changing their extensions from scss to css, tried with new files, moved the front-end to typescript too, deleted package-lock.json, node_modules, but nothing has worked so far.

Any response will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You probably need to copy the files from src directory into dist directory. (Ts is transpiled to javascript files, and then executed from new directory, hence js might not see the files you wanted as they are in different place). Its hard to say as we dont see how and what you did there

Comment: @Seti I don't compile the typescript, I directly run it using ts-node (on development mode)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].